# Azure Databricks job result permissions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I have a group of users that should have permission to see the log of a databricks job started by ADF and I don't want to give admin to them.
I found only documentation of how ytou can set the permitions for an individual job, I want to set it to all existing and future jobs. Is that possible?

PS.: I already enabled the "Job Visibility Control"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/access-control/jobs-acl#jobs-visibility

Comment: Can you give details about how you are able to do this for individual job?

Comment: Activate job access control as described on the link in my post, In workflows, job runs, access the job, click on edit permissions in the right panel, add the groups/users you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a job that is triggered as an ADF task, then it's not possible - permissions for a job run will be given only for a job defined inside the Databricks to users who has corresponding permissions on job itself. The reason for that is that ADF still uses old Jobs API 2.0 (function Submit Run) that doesn't allow to set permissions for job runs (it's possible to do with API 2.1).

You have following possibilities to fix that:

- if you continue to trigger jobs as ADF activities, then you can have a script that will go through the recent job runs and add view permissions to selected groups.
- You can use ADF web activity to trigger jobs defined inside the Databricks. Follow the steps outlined in [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/leverage-azure-databricks-jobs-orchestration-from-azure-data/ba-p/3123862).